# What is VMWare Cloud on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vmware-esxi, cloud

If AWS is powered by Amazon's own hypervisor layer then What is VMWare Cloud on AWS

As I basically understand VMWare provides virtualization products such as VMWare ESXi, NSX etc. They sit in between Hardware and Guest OS (User's OS). If I see AWS services, they are powered by Amazon's own virtualization layer. Basically, what I could get as an EC2 instance is nothing but a Virtual Machine running on AWS Cloud. VMWare's ESXi can give me an equivalent VM if I have VMWare's hypervisor layer. AWS offers its services in the form of IaaS (which is possible through virtualization of course their own) If I can think of using virtualization layer from VMWare then its not AWS Cloud services anymore it will be a vitualization layer from VMWare with its pros and cons. And what would be AWS services' role here? Then would Amazon just provide bare metal harware to run VMWare virtualization layer in this case? Then how exactly VMWare Cloud on AWS is going to work? I'm struggling to grasp the understanding of working of this.

Comment: Why did you post this? You're asking about a specific product, not a problem you're trying to solve. I can't say why SO mods deleted it, but I know why this question won't remain here on SF for very long.

Comment: They said post it on Serverfault it is made for such topics. I had also got a good satisfactory answer as well but suddenly after 2 and half years someone decided to downvote and delete it. I’m leaving it here just for people’s knowledge. I couldn’t find this information anywhere in any documents easily on AWS or VMWare. Though its a product, some popular products of the major companies end up being technology themselves

Comment: It's not a bad question...

Comment: This is a genuine question any decision-maker on the IT side of the business can get. I got this question when we were considering different technology selection options for a large project. This question shouldn't be closed with an "off-topic" remark. There is nothing wrong with this question.

Answer (score 2):

Answer by Kyle Ruddy on Stackoverflow.com where this question was originally on:
I moved it here because some people deleted it from there.

VMware Cloud on AWS is the usage of AWS bare-metal boxes to provide a vSphere environment comprised of vSphere (which is a VCSA VM and ESXi running on bare-metal), vSAN (storage), and NSX (networking) running completely in AWS datacenters and able to access those AWS services available in the deployed region.

The docs pages can probably help answer any further questions. There's also some videos available too: https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Cloud-on-AWS/index.html